# How to get a/b testing on the number of unique open?

Tags: civimail, abtesting

It seems that the A/B testing is looking at the total number of open. in one case, we were surprised to experience a big difference between two versions, but it turned out that one of the recipient opened the email dozen of time (most likely it was forwarded to a mailing list)

Is there a way to display and compare what really matters (the number of different contacts that opened, not the number of time they opened it)?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a code change and should be made at the api level:

api/v3/MailingAB.php, function civicrm_api3_mailing_a_b_graph_stats

(which in turn calls function in the CRM_Mailing_Event_BAO_Opened class)

Would be good to fix the definition of opened as you suggest across both A/B stats and the reports since that is the accurate and valid number